# Replace NA values in an entire dataframe with a random sample from a vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that's missing values. I want to fill those `NA` values not with a specific number, but instead randomly from a set of values in another vector.

```
ID <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
col1 <- c(5, 2, 1)
col2 <- c(8, 1, 6)
col3 <- c(NA, 2, 3)
col4 <- c(NA, 9, NA)
col5 <- c(NA, NA, NA)

replacementVals <- c(.1, .4, .7, .4, .3, .9, .4)

df <- data.frame(ID, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
df
  ID col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1  A    5    8   NA   NA   NA
2  B    2    1    2    9   NA
3  C    1    6    3   NA   NA
```

I've tried using a combination of `is.na()` and `sample` but I haven't gotten anything to work. I know that I could do 2 for-loops indexing on every cell, checking if it's `NA`, and if it is then sampling 1 value from the list:

```
for(row in 1:nrow(df)){
  for(col in 2:ncol(df)){
    if(is.na(df[row,col])) df[row,col] <- sample(replacementVals, 1)
  }
}
df
  ID col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1  A    5    8  0.9  0.4  0.7
2  B    2    1  2.0  9.0  0.4
3  C    1    6  3.0  0.4  0.7
```

But my actual dataframe is hundreds of thousands of rows and hundreds of columns, and time is a big factor. I'm hoping there's a more efficient way to go about it than brute-forcing it with for loops. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(across(, ~ replace(.x, is.na(.x), 
     sample(replacementVals, sum(is.na(.x)), replace = T))))
```

```
  ID col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1  A    5    8  0.9  0.1  0.4
2  B    2    1  2.0  9.0  0.9
3  C    1    6  3.0  0.9  0.4
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and it works perfectly, but just one small issue - my RStudio is throwing a "yield sign" in the margin for the middle row saying `missing argument to function call`. It's not an issue with the code, just annoying to look at. Do you have this issue as well?

Comment: Specifically, it's "yielding" after the `across(` expecting something before the comma. Hovering at the comma I get `missing argument to function call`

Comment: the default argument to `across` is `everything()`. I just omitted it because it is the default argument after all. Maybe try inserting it inside, inserted before the comma

Answer (score 2):

Here's vectorised base R way -

```
set.seed(3244)
inds <- is.na(df)
df[inds] <- sample(replacementVals, sum(inds), replace = TRUE)
df

#  ID col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
#1  A    5    8  0.4  0.1  0.3
#2  B    2    1  2.0  9.0  0.4
#3  C    1    6  3.0  0.9  0.9
```

Comment: This is initially what I tried with my actual dataset, but I kept getting the error `Subscript `inds` is a matrix, the data `sample(sampleDist, sum(inds), replace = TRUE)` must have size 1.` It does work for the specific example I provided, but it doesn't appear to work for my larger dataset. The `dplyr` option worked for me

Comment: Probably your dataset is a tibble unlike your example which is a dataframe and hence, you are getting this error. If you change tibble to dataframe then this answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

Loops are not bad necessarily, especially if you are not changing the size of objects in the loop. Nevertheless, I use an `apply` loop in my answer. You need the `replace = TRUE` argument in your call to sample if your `replacementVals` vector is smaller than the number of values that need to be replaced:

```
set.seed(1111) #  for reproducibility
df[2:6] <- apply(df[2:6], 2, FUN = function(x){
  hit <- which(is.na(x))
  x[hit] <- sample(x = replacementVals, size = length(hit), replace = TRUE)
  return(x)
})
df
#   ID col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
# 1  A    5    8  0.4  0.9  0.4
# 2  B    2    1  2.0  9.0  0.4
# 3  C    1    6  3.0  0.4  0.1
```